# Excel ActiveX Button is clickable, but does not work

Tags: excel, vba, button, activex

About a week ago, I found that all ActiveX buttons stopped working in all spreadsheets, when running on my computer.  They work on others just fine.  There had been no issues for the past year.

I know there was recently a Windows updates that caused a stir, preventing people from even being able to click on ActiveX buttons.  The issue I am experiencing seems to be different... I am able to click on the button (once clicked, it will show the dotted line around the perimeter of the button).  however, nothing happens.

I have these buttons created to open User forms.  I have checked to verify the PrivateSub code still exists to launch the form on the Button Click.

Since all my staff are still able to use the spreadsheets and ActiveX buttons, I am thinking there is something occurring locally on my computer, and it is not necessarily programming related, but I have had no luck finding any cause.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, I performed the suggested updates related to the Microsoft update flaw.  The issue I am experiencing happened about a week after that issue came up and was fixed.

Comment: Your not in design mode are you?

Comment: No, not in design mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the issue.  It appears as though my issue WAS still related to the Microsoft update.. I just happened to be experiencing a different symptom, and needed a different solution as well (rather than just delete MSForms.exd files)

I recompiled the projects (Open VBEditor, Debug Menu, Compile VBA Project), saved workbook, closed excel, and re-opened.  Everything worked as normal again.

Unfortunately, I need to do this for all files I work with which have ActiveX controls, which is several dozen.

Comment: This does not appear to be a permanent solution.... once someone else opens and saves the file, it reverts to the previous issue when I open.